# How can i convert a simple xml to json in jquery without using any plugins?

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I need to convert an xml document into json in jquery but without plugin and i m not able to find proper code and steps to proceed...

Comment: just curious: why reinventing the wheel while plugin can help?

Comment: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/  see if this can help.

Comment: how can i view the json code that is created using this plugin???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you-

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1054-jQuery-Demo-Working-With-XML-Documents.htm